# Angular looping a array of JSONs

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I currently have an array of JSONs that I am trying to print out to the screen by using a loop.  Currently I can get my results I want without the loop but when I try to convert it to a loop I run into some issues.  Any insight would be helpful.  Thank you.

This is my current code:

```
<div>
    <h2>Document Type</h2>
    <select>
        <option>Document Type : {{handoff[0].documentType}}</option>
        <option>Document Type : {{handoff[1].documentType}}</option>
        <option>Document Type : {{handoff[2].documentType}}</option>
        <option>Document Type : {{handoff[3].documentType}}</option>
        <option>Document Type : {{handoff[4].documentType}}</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option ng-repeat="temp in handoff">Document Type : {{temp[0].documentType}}</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option ng-repeat="temp in handoff">Document Type : {{temp.documentType}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My results for the first "select" are correct but for the second and third have no results.

Here is what the obj looks like:
[image]

```
"handoffs":{"0":{   "documentType":"0","conlID":"1230","userName":"CU0","handoff":"h=81878E9E772BCA176D868CA633BFB47D38274B1B209FD80856E56B47"
},"1":{"documentType":"1","conlID":"C010","userName":"A010","handoff":"ERROR: A temporary problem was encountered.  Please try your request again in a few minutes."},"3":{"documentType":"3","conlID":"C010","userName":"C10","handoff":"HANDOFF=81878E9E77FB56E56B47"}}
```

Comment: Can you post the controller code or at least what the handoff array looks like? and also can you clarify which part of your above code works and which doesn't?

Comment: all the options are missing with `value` attribute .. 3rd should work as its correct..Though I'd suggest you to go for using `ng-options`

Comment: @o4ohel : the controller code will not help at all as it's an API response.  The first SELECT works but the other 2 do not.  And I just updated the question to display the handoff structure.

Comment: @PankajParkar : Up voted b/c of the ng-options to clean up my code, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @SariRahal could you add you sample json response..instead of image?

Comment: @PankajParkar : I just added it.

Comment: since you're dealing with an object not an array the correct syntax would be : ng-repeat="(key, value) in handoffs"> {{value.documentType}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should correct you json structure & shouldn't have "0", "1" & "2" in object literals in your response, You could simply have an array so that your problem would get solved.

**Updated JSON**

```
{
    "handoffs": [{
            "documentType": "0",
            "conlID": "1230",
            "userName": "CU0",
            "handoff": "h=81878E9E772BCA176D868CA633BFB47D38274B1B209FD80856E56B47"
        },{
            "documentType": "1",
            "conlID": "C010",
            "userName": "A010",
            "handoff": "ERROR: A temporary problem was encountered.  Please try your request again in a few minutes."
        },{
            "documentType": "3",
            "conlID": "C010",
            "userName": "C10",
            "handoff": "HANDOFF=81878E9E77FB56E56B47"
        }]
    }
}
```

**Update**

@o4ohel suggested a good option, if you don't have any control over the data & don't wanted to change it. Then you should use the option

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in handoff">Document Type : {{value.documentType}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That's a good answer. But If you don't want to preprocess the object into an array, you could use the following syntax: <option ng-repeat="(key, temp) in handoffs">Document Type : {{temp.documentType}}</option>

Comment: For the record, I agree with @pankaj-parkar that it's better/makes more sense to have 'handoffs' be an array.